# Is there a way to include images outside of my project in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a project that is written using `C#` on the top of ASP.NET MVC 5 framework.

I have images located on `C:/web_images` that I want to make accessible from my app. In my views, I want to be able to write `~/images/abc.jpg` but my app would render the image located on `C:/web_images/abc.jpg`.

In the new ASP.NET Core framework, the same thing can be done using static files( by adding the following to the Configure method in the Startup class.)

```
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = blobFileProvider, //new PhysicalFileProvider("c:/web_images"),
        RequestPath = "/images"
    });
```

How can I create this virtual path using ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: Could you do it in the webserver config instead? In IIS you could just create a virtual directory, Most webservers will have a similar option. I tend to do this anyway as I'd rather let nginx pick up file requests than the ASP app.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270754/referring-an-image-that-is-located-on-my-c-drive-in-asp-net-mvc) question might help.

Answer (score 0):

User browser can't  access directly to webserver drive (c:).
The best way to do it is to create a .ashx who can allow users (views rendreds) to download files.
view exemple:

```
<img src="~/ProcessImage.ashx?filename=image1.pgp"/>
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

First option that came to my mind is to use Owin and get nuget package for serving static files, like this one [Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles/4.0.0/).

Second, more invasive approach is to create Symlink to given folder: [Symlink tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)

Third option: Host on IIS and create virtual directory.